# setBounds method isn't working properly?

Tags: java

Well the title explains it, basically the `setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)` method isn't working like I want it too as nothing is being displayed. The point of this code is to get the text from some text fields then close that window and and convert them to `JLabel` objects to be displayed on the screen but it doesn't do that. Here are some code fragments:

```
public class Create implements ActionListener {

    private JTextArea t1, t2, t3;
    private String s1 = t1.getText();
    private String s2 = t2.getText();
    private String s3 = t3.getText();
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            dispose();
            setVisible(false);
            t1 = new JTextArea(7, 17);
            t2 = new JTextArea(7, 17);
            t3 = new JTextArea(7, 17);

            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
            frame2.add(new Test(s1,s2,s3));
            frame2.setTitle("Title");  
            frame2.setSize(700,500);
            frame2.setResizable(true);
            frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame2.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

New class `Test`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private int w = 250, velx = 2, x = 330;
    Timer tm = new Timer(50,this);

    public Test(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
        setText(s1, s2, s3);
    }

    public void setText(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(s1);
        label1.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(s2);
        label2.setBounds(75, 20, 100, 20);
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel(s3);
        label3.setBounds(100, 20, 100, 20);
    }
}
```

*****String won't draw on top of rectangle*****

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){


       super.paintComponent(g);

       g.drawString("something", 300, 50);
       g.drawString("something", 50, 100);
       g.drawString("something", 50, 150);



}

public void paint(Graphics g){
     tm.setInitialDelay(10000);
     super.paint(g);
     Graphics2D graph2 = (Graphics2D)g;

     Shape Rect1 = new Rectangle2D.Float(330, 30, 250, 390);
     graph2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
     graph2.fill(Rect1);

     Shape Rect2 = new Rectangle2D.Float(x, 30, w, 390);
     graph2.setColor(Color.RED);
     graph2.fill(Rect2);

     tm.start();


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to add those label to your  `JPanel` , So that they can get Displayed

```
 public void setText(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(s1);
        label1.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(s2);
        label2.setBounds(75, 20, 100, 20);
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel(s3);
        label3.setBounds(100, 20, 100, 20);
        add(label1);// Add the label to your current JPanel
        add(label2);
        add(label3);

    }
```

When you need absolute positioning , you need to explicitly set the Layout to `Null`

> ```
> JPanel#setLayout(null)
> ```

**Update**

***How to draw Rectangle on JLabel .***

override the `paintComponent` method of the `JLabel`. It should first call `super.paintComponent`, so you get whatever the JLabel contains, then add your own drawing code after that.

```
@override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g)
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(xPos,yPos,width,height);
    g.fillRect(r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());  
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but wouldn't me adding the entire class to the JFrame in my other class automatically add the labels too?

Comment: In that case you need to add the labels to the panel  using `add(Component c)` method  , and then add the panel to your JFrame .
Check out the updated code

Comment: Thank you it worked, one last question, I drew a rectangle and when I try to position it absolutely on top of it my JLabel dissapears any ideas why?

Comment: You have to override the `paintComponent` method of JLabel , Check out the updated answer

Comment: Sorry. I just updated my code so you can see my code